# I can't solve this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE

Tags: php, mysql

error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\Pharmaceutical Distribution System\PDS\add-department-1.php on line 149

here is my php code for add options dynamically from php mysql.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Department</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="Department" required>
 <option>Select Department</option>
 <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
    $SqlResult = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT department_name from department_master");
    mysql_select_db('pds',$link)
    while($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($SqlResult))
    {
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $Row['department_name']; ?>"></option>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
    </select>
                                                                </div>
```

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon at the end of the line above it

Comment: well, read the error message. "unexpected T_WHILE". how many whiles do you have in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited for you

```
<div class="form-group">
         <label>Department</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="Department" required>
             <option>Select Department</option>
             <?php
                $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
                mysql_select_db('pds',$link);
                $SqlResult = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT department_name from department_master");

                while($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($SqlResult))
                {
                  ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $Row['department_name']; ?>"><?php echo $Row['department_name']; ?></option>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>
        </select>
</div>
```

Comment: As several people have pointed out, you were missing a ';' after `mysql_select_db('pds', $link)`